# How to add ReplayKit to a single scene SpriteKit app

Tags: ios

Using this code example it was trivial to add ReplayKit to a 'single view' iOS app and recoding and subsequent sending of video all worked well. How would I implement this functionality in a single scene SpriteKit app ?

```
import ReplayKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Start", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "startRecording")
    }

    func startRecording() {
        let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder()

        recorder.startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled(true) { [unowned self] (error) in
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                print(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Stop", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "stopRecording")
            }
        }
    }

    func stopRecording() {
        let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder()

        recorder.stopRecordingWithHandler { [unowned self] (preview, error) in
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Start", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "startRecording")

            if let unwrappedPreview = preview {
                unwrappedPreview.previewControllerDelegate = self
                self.presentViewController(unwrappedPreview, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func previewControllerDidFinish(previewController: RPPreviewViewController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```